# How to use port offset with arquillian?

Tags: maven-3, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have different projects with integration tests, starting an embedded wildfly to run the tests.
To be able to run them parallel I want to use the port offset, but it seems that arquillian doesn't recognize the offset.

Is there any possibility to use the offset? I don't want to use the hardcoded management port of the arquillian.xml, because it should be configurable as CLI parameter.

Thanks for any hints.